# WPF placement of Intellisense like PopUp below the selection start

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup

Hi I want to place a WPF Popup below the last character typed in a textbox just like we know it from intellisense in VS.

My actual Code looks like this is there a way to place it according the coordinates of the textboxex text?:

```
 <local:TextBoxAutoSuggestion Text="{Binding InputText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        x:Name="SearchPathTextBox"
                                        local:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsFocusOnInputTextBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Foreground="{DynamicResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"
                                        Background="Transparent"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        Height="45"
                                        Padding="5,0,30,0"
                                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                        CaretBrush="White"
                                        BindableSelectionStart="{Binding SelectionLengthInputText,Mode=TwoWay}">
          <i:Interaction.Triggers >
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
              <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextBoxFocusedChangedCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
              <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextBoxFocusedChangedCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
          </i:Interaction.Triggers>

          <local:TextBoxAutoSuggestion.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding EnterKeyPressedCommand}"
                        Key="Return" />
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding TabKeyPressedCommandinTextBox}"
                        Key="Tab" />
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding BackSpacePressedCommand}"
                        Key="Backspace" />
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SelectNextItemCommand}"
                        Key="Down" />
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SelectPreviousItemCommand}"
                        Key="Up" />

          </local:TextBoxAutoSuggestion.InputBindings>
        </local:TextBoxAutoSuggestion>
<Popup 
             Width="300"
             Margin="0,0,0,0"
             StaysOpen="False"
             Visibility="{Binding IsPopUpOpened, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
             IsOpen="{Binding IsPopUpOpened, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
             PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=SearchPathTextBox}"
             Placement="Bottom"
             IsEnabled="{Binding IsPopUpEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
             >
      <ListBox Margin="0,0,0,0"
               Visibility="{Binding IsPopUpOpened, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
               ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredPossibleSegments}"
               Foreground="{DynamicResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"
               Background="Transparent"
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSegment,Mode=TwoWay}"
               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
               Height="200"
                >
      </ListBox>
      </Popup>
```

The placement which I use right now is "Bottom".

Comment: I haven't done anything like this, but I guess it's all about calculating position of character and then positioning popup accordingly. Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-placement-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

I used horizontal offset property of the pop up and set it according the text length:

```
 <Popup 
             Width="300"
             Margin="0,0,0,0"
             StaysOpen="False"
             Visibility="{Binding IsPopUpOpened, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
             IsOpen="{Binding IsPopUpOpened, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
             PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=SearchPathTextBox}"
             Placement="RelativePoint"
             IsEnabled="{Binding IsPopUpEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
             HorizontalOffset="{Binding HorizontalPopUpPosition, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
             VerticalOffset="50"
        
             >
```

I experimented with the horizontal and found the best with this you need to find the best option for your position in your window.

```
   HorizontalPopUpPosition =330+ InputText.Length*5;
```